# GA4 exports only intraday tables to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery fully daily export for GA4 doesn't work. We have 5 events_intraday_YYYYMMDD tables and no events_YYYYMMDD in BigQuery.

Billing is correct, a service account is added to Google Cloud project.
We don't see any related errors in logs.
The integration was made accordingly to the instructions

What could be the issue?

Comment: It would be best to add more information to this question - some code is always good.

Comment: @MhluziBhaka there is no code. It is a native Google Analytics 4 -> BigQuery integration

Comment: Did you figure this out eventually? Was this because you hadn't enabled daily exports and that's why events_YYYYMMDD tables were never created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the daily export option for the intraday tables to be deleted. You can only do this if you have < 1m events. I explained the full behavior in this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409875/unioning-data-from-tables-to-get-over-the-1-million-events-daily-export-limit-fr/77551325#77551325).