# Unioning data from tables to get over the 1 Million events daily export limit from GA4 to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

So we have run into the problem of hitting the 1 Million events daily export limit from GA4 to Bigquery in the free edition. GA360 is too expensive for us, so we are looking for any alternatives.

I was wondering if this is as simple as tracking different parts of the app in different GA4 properties (separate tables) so that each property stays within the 1 Million / day export limit.

Then all I have to do is union (combine) the data and store that as a consolidated view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into this challenge recently and now solved it but it took us some stress and guesstimation in making it work. While Google offers a great way to go around this, sadly their sites are not documenting this case well. I am going to explain how we went around the 1 million events limit with fully native solutions that will take you 10 mins to implement.

- Go to Admin / BigQuery links / Your domain
- If you're reading this post, you'll see that there is a warning on your events being > 1m
- Under export types right below there is a daily export and a streaming export options
- If you're within the 3 days grace period keep daily export option on, and also select streaming export (reason below)
- If you're outside of the 3 days grace period and thus Google already paused your daily exports, unselect daily exports and select streaming exports

Daily behavior:

- If daily exports are still enabled when the daily export runs it'll create the events_$date table and delete the events_intraday_$date table. That's why for the first day it's ideal to keep the daily export option on. Otherwise your events_intraday_$date table will have partial data for the first day.
- If daily exports are disabled, your events will be in events_intraday_$date table and you will not see any events_$date tables. In our experience the structure of the tables are the same (there might be some differences but for our purposes they were practically the same).

Please note that Google is not being just difficult in offering this turnaround. You will incur some costs for streaming data, $0.01 per 200 MB to be exact ([details here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_ingestion_pricing)). For us this meant $0.05 / day for about 1m events so $1.5 / month; not remotely comparable to paying for GA.

Comment: I don't get it, when you started using streaming in addition to daily exports, you could overcome the 1 Million limitation? If it's so easy as this, what is the incentive to upgrade to GA360?

Comment: Speculating here:
From a buyer point of view no support, no SLAs, no advanced integrations, no accuracy guarantees, pretty basic integration etc etc.
From Google's point of view millions of (literally) potential new paying Google Cloud customers using an integration that they had already coded.

Comment: so you are able to export more than 1 Million events daily by switching on streaming. And the data is also archived for historical analysis? or is it only available for one day in the intraday table?

Comment: I thought intraday table could only hold data for one day. Are you saying that once you turn off the daily export, you can use intraday table as the regular events table? i.e. all data for multiple months going forward will be available in the intraday table?

Comment: Fact: for 20+ days intraday tables were untouched. Best guess for the future: I'd be surprised if the intraday tables get deleted somehow and my understanding is that the daily export process deletes the intraday tables for convenience / data integrity. As there are no other export mechanisms other than daily, no other deletion mechanisms. So when we turned the daily exports off it also turned off the daily intraday table deletion. This behavior is not documented, we're deducing from what we're seeing so far.

Comment: So I assume you now combine (union) the data from your old daily events table with new data in your intraday table if you want to have complete visibility of your data (current and historical)?

Comment: can you please provide an update regarding the above? I would be so grateful.

Comment: I have two days grace period left, would you recommend turning on streaming now, and disabling daily export? or would you recommend keeping daily export on until google itself turns it off?

Comment: Also, when I turn daily exports off / when google turns it off, and I switch over to streaming, will I still have access to the existing data of previous daily exports?