# Switching to streaming to overcome the 1 Million events per day export limit from GA4 to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

The Google documentation says:

```
Standard GA4 properties have a BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events for Daily (batch) exports. There is no limit on the number of events for Streaming export.
```

Does this mean that all I have to do to overcome this limit is to switch from batch to streaming? If so, will the intraday table (streaming table) be treated as my regular events table where all data of multiple days / weeks / months will be aggregated? If so, once I make the switch to streaming, can I union data from the new intraday table with my old batch events table for historical / comparitive analysis?

This seems a bit far fetched, why would anyone upgrade to GA360 if the alternative to overcoming the daily limit is so easy.

Answer (score 1):

no , It means using streaming option you access all your data of the current day using intraday table but the next day, the created 'events_(yesterday date)' table only contains the first millionth of events that occurred yesterday and no access to others. you can not solve this issue using union or joins with intraday tables, but you can restrict transferred events in GA4 or other solutions to overcome this issue.

Comment: thanks are you sure about this? have you experienced this yourself?

Comment: I have come across this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/77551325/23193953 that says something different!

Answer (score 0):

One option to overcome the 1M event export limit in GA4 is to implement [Parallel Tracking](https://reflectivedata.com/how-to-avoid-google-analytics-4-ga4-bigquery-export-quota-limit-of-1-million-hits/). While it's not 100% free, it's many times cheaper compared to GA360.

The implementation process is rather simple, and can be done using GTM, for example and the data export you get in your BigQuery instance is exactly the same as you'd get with the native export.